# Array push is not working in array forEach - Javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, mongodb, loops, foreach

I need to create a new array from iterating mongodb result. This is my code.

```
const result = await this.collection.find({
  referenceIds: {
    $in: [referenceId]
  }
});

var profiles = [];

result.forEach(row => {
  var profile = new HorseProfileModel(row);

  profiles.push(profile);

  console.log(profiles); //1st log
});

console.log(profiles); //2nd log
```

I can see update of profiles array in 1st log. But 2nd log print only empty array.

Why i couldn't push item to array?

Update
I think this is not related to promises. HorseProfileModel class is simply format the code.

```
const uuid = require("uuid");

class HorseProfileModel {

    constructor(json, referenceId) {

        this.id = json.id || uuid.v4();
        this.referenceIds = json.referenceIds || [referenceId];
        this.name = json.name;
        this.nickName = json.nickName;
        this.gender = json.gender;
        this.yearOfBirth = json.yearOfBirth;
        this.relations = json.relations;
        this.location = json.location;
        this.profilePicture = json.profilePicture;
        this.horseCategory = json.horseCategory;
        this.followers = json.followers || [];
    }

}

module.exports = HorseProfileModel;
```

Comment: @Rajesh No he is pushing a new profile into a profile list...

Comment: Is `forEach` `Array.prototype.forEach` or is it the MongoDB version ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Wait till all items from mongoDB query are processed before continuing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46451566/wait-till-all-items-from-mongodb-query-are-processed-before-continuing)

Comment: Why don't you try the cursor's `map()` method as `let profiles = result.map(r => new HorseProfileModel(r))`?

Comment: @jonas - no this is java script loop.

Comment: @jonasw got it what you mean. Thanks. I'll not comment like that.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
 await this.collection.find(...)
```

that returns an array of the found data right? Nope, that would be to easy. find *immeadiately* returns a *Cursor*. Calling *forEach* onto that does not call the sync `Array.forEach` but rather `Cursor.forEach` which is async and weve got a race problem. The solution would be promisifying the cursor to its result:

```
const result = await this.collection.find(...).toArray();
```

[Reference](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/2.2/api/Cursor.html)